debugging Manta 1.6.0 with gdb
I'm trying to run manta on RHEL 8.  I built it using gcc 9.2.0 with --build-type=RelWithDebInfo
The following command throws a "segmentation fault, core dumped".  Running it under gdb, doing a "bt" when it crashes, consistently gets me a stack trace with 8733 frames, of which ~8700 are
searchRepeats (opt=..., index=aNumber, word=..., wordIndices=..., wordStack=..., repeatWords=...) at manta-1.6.0.release_src/src/c++/lib/assembly/IterativeAssembler.cpp:586

Yes, always that line.  aNumber ranges from 20 up to 33319.
manta/1.6.0/libexec/GenerateSVCandidates --threads 10 --align-stats alignmentStats.xml --graph-file svLocusGraph.bin --bin-index 0 --bin-count 1 --max-edge-count 10 --min-candidate-sv-size 8 --min-candidate-spanning-count 3 --min-scored-sv-size 50 --ref GCA_000001405.15_GRCh38_no_alt_short_headers_nonACTG_to_N.fa --candidate-output-file svHyGen/candidateSV.0000.vcf --tumor-output-file svHyGen/tumorSV.0000.vcf --chrom-depth chromDepth.txt --edge-runtime-log svHyGen/edgeRuntimeLog.0000.txt --edge-stats-log results/stats/svCandidateGenerationStats.xml --edge-stats-report results/stats/svCandidateGenerationStats.tsv --tumor-align-file sample.bam

These are the top stack frames.  So I'm assuming the problem is running out of memory
#0  0x0000155554637b4e in _int_malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x0000155554639982 in malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x000000000070ddd5 in operator new (sz=81) at /research/bsi/tools/shared/gcc-9.2.0/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/new_op.cc:50
        p = <optimized out>
#3  0x000000000078920d in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_mutate (this=this@entry=0x15555419d1f0, __pos=__pos@entry=40, __len1=<optimized out>, __s=__s@entry=0x0, __len2=__len2@entry=1)
    at /research/bsi/tools/shared/build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc:310
        __how_much = 0
        __new_capacity = 80
        __r = <optimized out>


This is a loaded system.  How do I give manta more memory?
Has anyone seen this problem?


Not good; I suggest you file an issue on their github if you haven't already (https://github.com/Illumina/manta/issues), and also post this to https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ in case someone there has experienced/solved the problem. Good luck!

The archive is read only now
